# Yii Framework Tutorial - file not found

Tags: yii

I am in the process of learning the Yii Framework. I have been following [this](http://www.sterlingsavvy.com/tutorials/index.php?t=1&l=10)

Tutorial. I have followed all the steps and have by index page loading. In my index.php page I point to two other pages located in

> protected/views/message

The following is the code in my index.php located in the message folder mentioned above.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p> To view our message go to... <?php echo CHtml::link('Here', '/message/show')?> </p>
    <p> To edit our message go to... <?php echo CHtml::link('Here', '/message/edit')?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

"message" is the ID I gave when generating the model and controller through the yii shell application.

The problem is, after the above page loads, and I click on any one of the above URLs, it points to

> "localhost:8080/message/show"

and

> "localhost:8080/message/edit"

, whereas the real location of these files is

> "localhost:8080/test/protected/views/message/..."

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: I think you need to know more about MVC philosophy - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553988/mvc-books-tutorials-about-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an `array()` as the second parameter:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Here', array('/message/show'))?>
```

Check [normalizeUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#normalizeUrl-detail) to understand it. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you :) so whenever the data type is  "mixed" do I use an array ?

Comment: That 'mixed' in the documentation means that the parameter can be either 'string' or 'array'. So whenever you want to call an action of the controller it's better to use and array('controller/action') than a simple string 'controller/action' to avoid conflicts in the route.

Comment: Thanks again... @Puigcerber one more question. What are these possible conflicts ?

Comment: Like what just happened to you now, showing "localhost:8080/message/show" instead of "localhost:8080/test/message/show". It can happens also when you are inside of a module, for example user, it might show you something like "localhost:8080/test/user/message/show".

Answer (score 2):

Just read [Yii tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/index), it's really good.
Topic about [URL Managment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) is suitable for your question, you can find answers.
(by the way, Yii has only one entry point - index.php, there is no direct access to files in 'protected' folder, 'protected' folder must be protected :) urlManager does special work for routing requests )

Comment: Thanks! So accessing any other page has to be handled through the framework?